# Export HTML table to Excel and set destination folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, export

I have found many Javascript/jQuery methods for exporting HTML tables to Excel, and they all download to the default location. Does anyone know how to set your own destination download folder location for the exported Excel file without using a plugin?

Comment: It's not possible to set the download location. It's set by the browser at a lower level than JS code has access to

Comment: It will be a big security issue if any browser allow to specify the download target folder.So the answer is &quot;Not possible&quot;

Answer (score 0):

Found [a function that opens a "Save As" dialog allowing the user to choose the download location.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065108/export-to-excel-script)

```
function exportToExcel(tableID){
    var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6' style='height: 75px; 
    text-align: center; width: 250px'>";
        var textRange; var j=0;
        tab = document.getElementById(tableID); // id of table

        for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++)
        {

            tab_text=tab_text;

            tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase()+"</tr>";
            //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
        }

        tab_text= tab_text+"</table>";
        tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, ""); //remove if u want links in your table
        tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); //remove if u want images in your table
        tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); //remove input params

        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer

        {
            txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
            txtArea1.document.write( 'sep=,\r\n' + tab_text);
            txtArea1.document.close();
            txtArea1.focus();
            sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"asd.xls");
        }

        else {
           sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));


        }

        return (sa);
    }
```